# How to check whether my windows 8.1 in laptop is genuine or not?

Tags: windows

I bought and new laptop with windows 8.1 pre-installed in it and now windows 10 has got released. I want to check if its genuine or not because some of guys who used my lap said that its pirated windows os.

I need to confirm it .please help

Comment: If Windows 8.1 is activated, and you purchased the device from the OEM, then the device is genuine.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/howtotell/Hardware.aspx#PCPurchase

Comment: run **slmgr.vbs -dli** and if it shows OEM you are fine, if KMS/MAK it is a pirated Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can usually find a Windows logo sticker at the bottom or under your battery.

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0EbP.jpg) one, for example:
[image]

If you are not sure follow [these](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/howtotell/Software.aspx#Packaging) steps to confirm or call your local Microsoft support.

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't say "COA", just a plain sticker with 3D effects. Also, note the "usually" part. Pirates will not bother with this. I'm aware that the license is in the firmware.

Comment: Anyone could put a sticker like that on a device.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree, but pirates probably don't... They spell things wrong, let alone forge a 3D sticker.